# Найчарівливіша — слово суто для художньої літератури?

Tags: вживання-слів

У книзі "Черепахи аж до низу" Джона Гріна знайшла слово "найчарівливіша":

> Але ти — ще й найчарівливіша людина, яку я коли-небудь знала, і ти не схожа на гірчицю.

Форма цікава, я раніше такого не чула, якщо чесно.
Почала шукати, дізналася, що це слово використовує Андрухович. Але у словниках нічого не знайшла.

Це слово підходить лише для художньої літератури? Чи воно є літературною нормою?

Answer (score 5):

Зустрічаємо це слово також і в інших творах, наприклад "[Атлант розправив плечі](http://wikisentence.com.ua/%D0%9D/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)":

> Найчарівливіший ляпас, який я отримав за все своє життя, до того ж –
>   цілком заслужено.

В творах [Шевченка](http://diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/3847/file.pdf) ( "Мандрівка з приємністю та й не без моралі", ст. 217 книги):

> Який  ви  ласкавий  артист,  —   промовила вона  й  зробила 
>   найчарівливішу  гримасу.  —   Як завжди!

В тому ж СУМі наводиться безліч інших прикладів, також й інші значення слова ( "Який впливає чарами" та "Який є наслідком впливу таких чарів"), де немає позначки "**заст**".

Слово є в словнику, зустрічається у багатьох українських авторів, тому ми спокійно можемо вживати його, однак як було сказано в коментарях, воно не є широковживаним.

Можете також використати синоніми, щоб замінити слово "чарівливий":

> повен чару <чарів>, р. чарівкий, зап. чаруючий, (сон тощо) ЧАРІВНИЙ.

Answer (score 3):

Твірне слово до **найчарівливіша**, очевидно, *чарівлива". У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/charivlyvyj) знаходимо це слово з позначкою *застаріле*:

> ЧАРІВЛИ́ВИЙ, а, е.
>
> 1. **заст**. Який містить у собі чари (у 1, 2 знач.).

Оскільки, воно застаріле, то, зрозуміло, що воно  не є літературним.

Comment: а застарілість слова точно свідчить про його нелітературність?

Comment: я б радше зробив висновок «…то зрозуміло, що воно не є **широковживаним**».